# iframes in IE7 as form upload target?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an iframe with the id of uploadtarget on my page.

```
<iframe id="uploadTarget" name="uploadTarget" src="" ></iframe>
```

In my js I set the forms target to the iframe

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
        this.target = 'uploadTarget';
        document.getElementById("uploadTarget").onload = uploadDone; 
    });
```

This does not work in IE7 & 8.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First:* you're mixing jQuery with normal JavaScript. Use

```
$('#uploadTarget').load(uploadDone);
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("uploadTarget").onload = uploadDone;
```

to get a neater code.

*Second:*
My guess is that IE doesn't allow you to change the target of a `<form>` anymore once the form was submitted. If you abort submit, and then programmatically resubmit the form after you've changed the `target` things may work.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    if($(this).attr('target')!=='uploadTarget'){
       $(this).attr('target','uploadTarget');

       event.preventDefault();

       this.submit();//Now submit the form. This should call this function again.
    }else{
       $('#uploadTarget').load(uploadDone);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just added the target to my iframe in the html and it works in chrome. It appears that the target is not being recognised in ie, any ideas why?

Comment: It's a bit more, unfortunately: .load event in iframe in IE8 is, well, complicated.